# TypeError: xeger() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm trying to run a command line but it fails with error `TypeError: xeger() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`.
 I can't understand the reason because I send only two params to xeger.xeger: `out = xeger.xeger(pattern, limit)`. I understand that `self` is hidden but automatically added to the arguments list so I've changed to `xeger.xeger(self, pattern, limit)` and the function signature to `def generate(self, limit, pattern)` but I still get the same error.

```
import xeger
import click
@click.command()
@click.option('--limit', default=10, help='Number of chars to return')
@click.option('--pattern', prompt='pattern to match', help='regexp to match')

def generate(limit, pattern):
    """Simple program that receives a pattern and returns a matching string."""
    out = xeger.xeger(pattern, limit)
    click.echo('%s' % out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   generate()
```

Run and error:

```
python rand.py --limit 230
pattern to match: asda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rand.py", line 13, in <module>
    generate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 716, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 696, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 889, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "rand.py", line 9, in generate
    out = xeger.xeger(pattern, limit)
TypeError: xeger() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at their sourcecode, there are 2 things you could do:

1. Do not send the `limit` argument - where it would default to 10.
2. Initialize it slightly differently.

Something like this

```
from xeger import Xeger

_x = Xeger(limit=limit)
out = _x.xeger(pattern)
```